# How does flatmap really work in Scala

Tags: scala

I took the scala odersky course and thought that the function that Flatmap takes as arguments , takes an element of Monad and returns a monad of different type.

```
trait M[T] {
    def flatMap[U](f: T => M[U]): M[U]
}
```

On Monad M[T] , the return type of function is also the same Monad , the type parameter U might be different.

However I have seen examples on internet , where the function returns a completely different Monad. I was under impression that return type of function should the same Monad. Can someone simplify the below to explain how flapmap results in the actual value instead of Option in the list.

Is the List not a Monad in Scala.

```
val l= List(1,2,3,4,5)
def f(x:int) = if (x>2) Some(x) else None
l.map(x=>f(x))
//Result List[Option[Int]] = List( None , None , Some(3) , Some(4) , Some(5))
l.flatMap(x=>f(x))
//Result: List(3,4,5)
```

Comment: Disgustingly enough, you can put pretty much whatever signature you want onto `flatmap`, `map`, and `filter` and still use `for` comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the fact that `M[T]`is not a monad by itself. It's a type constructor. It becomes a monad when it's associated with two operators: `bind` and `return` (or `unit`). There are also monad laws these operators must satisfy, but let's omit them for brevity. In Haskell the type of `bind` is:

```
class Monad m where
  ...
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

where `m` is a type constructor. Since Scala is OO language `bind` will look like (first argument is self):

```
trait M[T] {
    def bind[U](f: T => M[U]): M[U]
}
```

Here `M === m`, `T === a`, `U === b`. `bind` is often called `flatMap`. In a pure spherical world in a vacuum that would be a signature of `flatMap` in OO language. Scala is a very practical language, so the real signature of `flatMap` for `List` is:

```
final def flatMap[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

It's not `bind`, but will work as a monadic `bind` if you provide `f` in the form of `(A) => List[B]` and also make sure that `That` is `List[B]`. On the other hand Scala is not going to watch your back if you provide something different, but will try to find some meaningful conversion (e.g. `CanBuildFrom` or something else) if it exists.

**UPDATE**

You can play with `scalac` flags (`-Xlog-implicits`, `-Xlog-implicit-conversions`) to see what's happening:

```
scala> List(1).flatMap { x => Some(x) }
<console>:1: inferred view from Some[Int] to scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] via scala.this.Option.option2Iterable[Int]: (xo: Option[Int])Iterable[Int]
       List(1).flatMap { x => Some(x) }
                                  ^
res1: List[Int] = List(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, perhaps confusingly, the signature you gave is not actually correct, since it's really (in simplified form):

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Traversable[B]
```

Since the compiler is open-source, you can actually see what it's doing (with its full signature):

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  def builder = bf(repr) // extracted to keep method size under 35 bytes, so that it can be JIT-inlined
  val b = builder
  for (x <- this) b ++= f(x).seq
  b.result
}
```

So you can see that there is actually no requirement that the return type of `f` be the same as the return type of `flatMap`.

Comment: There is no need to have a look at the compiler source, that's documented in the publish Scaladoc about the Scala library

Answer (score 1):

The `flatmap` found in the standard library is a much more general and flexible method than the monadic bind method like the `flatMap` from Odersky's example.

For example, the full signature of flatmap on List is

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

Instead of requiring the function passed into flatmap to return a List, it is able to return any `GenTraversableOnce` object, a very generic type.

flatmap then uses the implicit `CanBuildFrom` mechanism to determine the appropriate type to return.

So when you use flatmap with a function that returns a List, it is a monadic bind operation, but it lets you use other types as well.

Comment: `List` forms a perfectly good monad. Just because you can do *more* than a normal monad doesn't prevent it from *being* a monad. Restricting `flatMap` to return `List` is perfectly fine and generates the basic monadic bind. Otherwise put, the fact that monadic bind *usually* has the name `flatMap` should not be enough to disqualify `List` from being a monad just because it's bind operation is named differently. If there's some `trait Monadic[M[A] <: Monadic[M]] { def flatMap(f: A => M[B]): B }`, you can say that `List` is not `Monadic`, but its wrong to say that this means it isn't a monad.